# Position items so that their centers align with center of another element in CSS (JS only if necessary)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a root element and I'd like other items to be aligned relative to that root element, so that their centers line up. In this example http://jsfiddle.net/4a78mqso/ there should be one element to the right, left, above and below the root element.

If I add a class of `r` (right) to an element, it should appear to the right of the root element, and it and the root element should be in a horizontal line and their centers should line up. Similarly, if I add a class of `u` (up), it should appear above the root element, and it and the root element should be in a vertical line and their centers should line up.

I can tinker with the values in the CSS to get it to position exactly so the centers line up, but the elements in the HTML are dynamic and can change width and height, so the values shouldn't depend on exact numbers.

```
<div class='root' style='margin: 300px'>
root
  <div class='r' style='width: 50px; height: 50px;'>right</div>
  <div class='l' style='width: 30px; height: 30px;'>left</div>
  <div class='u' style='width: 80px; height: 80px;'>up</div>
  <div class='d' style='width: 200px; height: 200px;'>down</div>
</div>
```

Ideally I'd like to do this without JS, is it possible with CSS only or will JS be necessary?

Comment: Can you add a drawing or some illustration of the expected end result ?

Comment: Probably something like this …? http://jsfiddle.net/4a78mqso/7/

Answer (score 0):

You can use css grid for the layout.
Like:
[this adjustment to your code - jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4a78mqso/20/)

```
<div class='root'>

    <div class="grid-item">

    </div>

    <div class="grid-item">
        <div style="text-align: center">
            <div class='u' style='width: 80px; height: 80px;'>up</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-item">

    </div>

    <div class="grid-item">
        <div class='l' style='width: 30px; height: 30px;'>left</div>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-item">
        root
    </div>

    <div class="grid-item">
        <div class='r' style='width: 50px; height: 50px;'>right</div>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-item">

    </div>

    <div class="grid-item">
        <div style="text-align: center;">
            <div class='d' style='width: 200px; height: 200px;'>down</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-item">

    </div>
</div>
<style>
    html {
        position: absolute;
        top: 100px;
        left: 500px;
    }
    .root {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
      align-content: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }

    .r {
      background-color: green;
    }

    .l {
      background-color: blue;
    }

    .u {
      display: inline-block;
      background-color: red;
      text-align: center;

    }

    .d {
      position: relative;
      background-color: yellow;
      text-align: center;

    }
    /* You don't really need this class I just put it there to show where the 
       grid items are */
    .grid-item {

    }
</style>
```

Comment: The absolute positioning from the example is needed so it can be used to have things floated around in the document but still relative to the root element.

Comment: :/ So put a div container around the root and make it: position: absolute;

Comment: or add the absolute positioning to the 'html' element. http://jsfiddle.net/dsbaileyfreelancer/gxfc8d4h/

Comment: after wrestling with the jsfiddle interface here is my result corrected: http://jsfiddle.net/dsbaileyfreelancer/gxfc8d4h/

Comment: Just change the position in the css 'html' element tag and it moves the arrangement to where ever you want.